How can I setup ros2 jazzy to be able to list nodes while offline with ros2 node list?
Hey I'm setting up a new install of ros jazzy on a fresh install of ubuntu 24. I have literally done nothing besides install jazzy on this partition. I was running the demo nodes talker and listener as a test. When running offline without wifi, the nodes run correctly and log their contents to the file in .ros/log. However, when I run ros2 node list, it doesn't list any nodes. Why?
Similarly, when I run ros2 topic list, it only returns /rosout and /parameter_event. Critically, it does not show /chatter
Also as far as hardware, I'm running a Razer Blade 15 fom 2023.
I also can't echo /chatter when offline but I can echo /rosout which is updating with the output of the nodes.
Upon further testing, I've realized that this issue only arises when I make nodes after ending the wifi. If I make the node while connected to wifi and then quit the wifi, I am still able to list out the nodes and topics associated with the wifi-node.

Configure DDS to use a more reliable network interface or adjust the discovery settings to handle network changes better. You can set the environment variable to force DDS to use a specific network interface
export ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1

if it works add it tou your .bashrc
Run diagnostic tools to see more detailed information about what ROS 2
ros2 doctor

you can check this documentation to have a more profound idea
https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Configuring-ROS2-Environment.html

I’ve also found that just restarting the daemon fixed my issue.
